# Cannot edit the get only variable in swift

Tags: swift

The function `today()` returns a number. To get this number I do:

```
var dateToday: Int { return self.today() }
```

Now I want to increment the `dateToday` variable by doing `dateToday+=1` but I get the error: "Cannot assign to value: 'dateToday' is a get-only property"

How can I assign the return value to a normal integer which I can edit?

Basically, I have a button which needs to increments the date variable. But first I need that variable defined outside the button function and then increment it inside the button function.

Using Swift 3

Comment: Why not declared `var dateToday = today()` ?

Comment: This is swift. It gives the error: Cannot use instance member 'today' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Comment: show your today() method. You need to do this inside viewDidLoad after initialization

Comment: `func today() -> Int {
        let dateAdded: Int = calendar.component(.day, from: date as Date)
        return dateAdded
    }`

Comment: just do `var day: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date()) }` it wll always return todays day number

Comment: or create an extension `extension Date {
    var day: Int { return Calendar.current.component(.day, from: self) }
}` and get the day from the date. `Date().day`

Answer (score 0):

You've written it as, well, a get only property.  Just use

```
var dateToday = self.today()
```

You'll probably have a different issue with incrementing it though...Just doing +=1 isn't going to work unless you've done something I'm unaware of.

EDIT: Nevermind, I was thinking dateToday was a Date, but I see you have it as an Int.  Nothing to see here. :-p

Answer (score 0):

You've declared `dateTime` here as a computed property of the containing class, which doesn't sound like what you want. You can declare it as a local variable. For example, in a function:

```
func foo() {
    var dateTime = today()
}
```

Or, as a variable property on a class:

```
class Bar {
    var dateTime: Int = 0
    init() {
        dateTime = today()
    }

    func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        dateTime += 1
    }
```

Does that make sense?

Comment: The only problem here is, I want to increment the dateTime variable but since it is in a function, it can't access that variable.

Comment: Basically, I have a button which needs to increments the date variable. But first I need that variable defined outside the button function and then increment it inside the button function.